# React Native FlatList on scroll produces whitespace

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to load large amount of data through FlatList but the problem that I am facing is that during the scrolling it appears whitespace I have seen this question also in different places but none of them tells how to solve this properly.

Data i get through my API

My current FlatList:

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.todayFixtures}
      renderItem={this.renderTournaments}
      extraData={this.state.refresh}
      keyExtractor ={(item, index) => item.tournamentId}
    />
```

and renderTournaments:

```
renderTournaments(fix) {
return <FootballDetail key={fix.tournamentId} todayFixture={fix} />;
}
```

While here is the FootballDetail:

```
sadasd
class FootballDetail extends Component {
state = {
fixtureToday: []
}
componentWillMount() {
//console.log(this.props.todayFixture.item);
this.setState({fixtureToday: this.props.todayFixture.item[0].matches});
}
constructor(props){
 super(props)
}
_onPressButton(fixture) {
Alert.alert(fixture.teamA + " - " + fixture.teamB)
}
renderTodayFixtures() {
  const { status, teams, teamResult } = styles;
  return this.state.fixtureToday.map((fixture) =>
    <CardSection>
      <View style={status} >
        {CommonFunctions.getStatus(fixture)}
      </View>
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="white" style={teams} onPress={() 
      => { this._onPressButton(fixture) }}>
        <View>
          <Text>{fixture.teamA}</Text>
          <Text>{fixture.teamB}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <View style={teamResult}>
        <Text>{fixture.teamAResult}</Text>
        <Text>{fixture.teamBResult}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/img/notification_tab.png')} style={{width: 22, height: 22}} />
      </View>
    </CardSection>
)
}
render () {
 return (
  <Card>
    <CardSection>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.tournamentTxt}>{this.props.todayFixture.item[0].tournamentName}: {this.props.todayFixture.item[0].tournamentStage}</Text>
      </View>
    </CardSection>
    {this.renderTodayFixtures()}
  </Card>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Please share a sample screen shot if possible. Moreover how are you getting the data ? (Through Firebase, API's or locally), If so how are you structuring the data. Therefore please share sample data declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play windowSize prop of FlatList. If this is very low, it can result in blank screens, if this is very high, it can occupy a lot of memory.

For reference https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist#windowsize

Comment: i tried but again it appears whitespace also i increased to 100 but then it had many problems with onPress function

Answer (score 0):

Why on your `keyExtractor` props, are you adding `index` if you don't use it ?

You should try to put your `FootballDetail` component to a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)

It will avoid rerendering of your component and improve perfs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a solution that is available in the FlatList Documentation that is [getItemLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#getitemlayout).

So basically for this approach to work you have to specify the height of your card or row item in flatList for eg: (height: 100) of your render item and the Text you use inside of the renderItem add the prop numberOfLines={1} so that it won't mess the card UI on dynamic content.
Note: Use Pure Component in renderItem, keyExtractor and intialNumberToRender={list.length}

Answer (score -1):

Responsiveness may suffer when you considerably increase the windowSize because rendering content may interfere with responding to button taps or other interactions so its better to take a moderate value and you can use a **placeholder** for items so that till data is loaded user doesn't see blank screen.

[image]